# Using an ArrayAdapter for a ListView in a different tab/Fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I'm deriving an ArrayList of data from my Activity that implements an interface in a method called `getList()`.
I have the necessary Adapter to wire the data and arrange the display. I also make use of tabs in my solution and created Fragments for each one. Each tab contains a ListView to which I want to pass different forms of the ArrayList of data to.

I've looked into bundling, args, parcelable route without success. The current paradigm of achieving my task is using the interface to access data in different Fragments.

I've done lots of reading and tried many routes, but I am struggling with populating the different tabs with ListViews with data from my Activity.

I have previously passed the data to a ListView that I added in my activity_main.xml, however the result is that it covers the other display on the other tabs/Fragments such that no matter what tab is clicked the list remains the same.

I want to be able to click on different tabs and see the list of data coming from the Activity in whatever order I want it to be according to the tab name (i.e.: alphabetical, chronological order). Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Below is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface{

    private Tab1Recents fragment;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private final int PICK = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getList();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            // calling OnActivityResult with intenet And Some conatct for Identifie
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK);
        }
    });
}

public class Android_Contact {
    public String android_contact_Name = "";
    public String android_contact_TelefonNr = "";
    public int android_contact_ID = 0;
}

public ArrayList<Android_Contact> getList() {
    ArrayList<Android_Contact> arrayListAndroidContacts = new ArrayList<Android_Contact>();

    Cursor cursor_Android_Contacts = null;
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    try {
        cursor_Android_Contacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    } catch (
            Exception ex
            )
    {
        Log.e("Error on contact", ex.getMessage());
    }
    if (cursor_Android_Contacts.getCount() > 0)

    {

        while (cursor_Android_Contacts.moveToNext()) {

            Android_Contact android_contact = new Android_Contact();
            String contact_id = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String contact_display_name = cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));


            android_contact.android_contact_Name = contact_display_name;


            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor_Android_Contacts.getString(cursor_Android_Contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                        , null
                        , ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?"
                        , new String[]{contact_id}
                        , null);

                while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    android_contact.android_contact_TelefonNr = phoneNumber;

                }
                phoneCursor.close();
            }

            arrayListAndroidContacts.add(android_contact);

        }


        Collections.sort(arrayListAndroidContacts, new Comparator<Android_Contact>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Android_Contact name2, Android_Contact name1) {
                return name1.android_contact_Name.compareTo(name2.android_contact_Name);
            }
        });
        Collections.reverse(arrayListAndroidContacts);

        Adapter_for_Android_Contacts adapter = new Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(this, arrayListAndroidContacts);

        ListView listView_Android_Contacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_Android_Contacts);

        listView_Android_Contacts.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    return arrayListAndroidContacts;
}


public class Adapter_for_Android_Contacts extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<Android_Contact> mList_Android_Contacts;

    //< constructor with ListArray >
    public Adapter_for_Android_Contacts(Context mContext, List<Android_Contact> mContact) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mList_Android_Contacts = mContact;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mList_Android_Contacts.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList_Android_Contacts.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.contactlist_android_items, null);
        TextView textview_contact_Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_android_contact_name);
        textview_contact_Name.setText(mList_Android_Contacts.get(position).android_contact_Name);
        view.setTag(mList_Android_Contacts.get(position).android_contact_Name);
        return view;
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:

                Tab2AZ tab2 = new Tab2AZ();
                return tab2;
            case 1:
                Tab1Recents tab1 = new Tab1Recents();
                return tab1;
            case 2:
                Tab3Location tab3 = new Tab3Location();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                Tab4Groups tab4 = new Tab4Groups();
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "A-Z";
            case 1:
                return "RECENT";
            case 2:
                return "LOCATION";
            case 3:
                return "TAGS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**An example Fragment looks like this**

```
  public class Tab1Recents extends Fragment {
        MyInterface myInterface;

        public void onAttach(MainActivity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            try {
                myInterface = (MyInterface) activity;
            } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onViewSelected");
            }

    }


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_recent, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Activity XML picture below while other tabs/Fragments simply feature a ListView in them.

Current result is no ListView in preview or running. all other xml tabs are visible and operational, but do not have any of the ListViews inflated which is what I am trying to achieve

[image: layout]

Comment: Why does your ViewPager contain a ListView?

Answer (score 0):

> Current result is no listview in preview or running ... all other xml tabs ... do not have any of the listviews inflated which is what I am trying to achieve

You need the ListView inside of the Fragment layout, so `tab1_recent.xml`, for example, not inside of the ViewPager of `activity_main.xml`.

A ViewPager needs an adapter just like a ListView to display data. It's like if you had this in your XML. You shouldn't expect that TextView to be shown inside of the list layout...

```
<ListView>
    <TextView />
</ListView>
```

---

As far as loading the data from the Activity to the Fragment... Why? Does each fragment hold the exact same list to display in each listview's adapter?

Just load the data from the fragment. If you have to get the data from the activity, then you can have something like

```
private List data;
// someAdapter
// someListView

public void onAttach(Context c) {
    super.onAttach(c);

    // needing to cast the context is a bad-design
    if (c instanceof MainActivity) {
        data = ((MainActivity) c).getList();
        if (data != null) {
           // someAdapter = new adapter(data);
           // someListView.setAdapter(someAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The fragments all have listviews as well. The ListView in the ViewPager was because that was one way I was able to get closer to desired result. The fragments hold the same data in different arrangements which is done by use of comparators. Deriving the data from the fragment would not be more efficient as I would still have to share the data with another fragment.

Comment: Well, like I said, you can call getActivity().getList(), but that just seems like a bad design to me

Comment: What is the truest proper way of doing this?

Comment: I don't really know what you are needing to do. I would try not to put duplicate data within different UI elements.

Comment: It's not duplicate data because they are filtered differently. So its passing data to a Listview from Activity to Fragment. PS thanks for your time.

Comment: An array list of parcelables can be passed into Fragments fine from an Activity. Your current problem preventing you from that is that `getItem` in the view pager adapter is always returning a new fragment. You setup the listview adapter with a list of objects, right? Why don't you store a list of Fragments in the view pager adapter so you can get a Fragment at that  position, and send data to it?